# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**Вот код:**

```
@WithUserDetails(value = "admin")
@Sql(value = {"/user_before.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(value = {"/user_after.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class ChatTest  {
}
```

В какой-то момент перестала работать инициализация `UserDetailsService`, что приводит к показанной ниже ошибке. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(setupBefore=TEST_METHOD, userDetailsServiceBeanName=, value=admin)

    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: registrationService,userService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.findUserDetailsService(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:123)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: registrationService,userService - видимо где то тут

Comment: Где конфигурация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что у вас в конфигурации Spring есть два бина типа указанного в ошибке

> NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: **registrationService,userService**

Поскольку Spring по умолчанию ваярит бины по типу, то он не может определить какой из бинов подставить.

Например:

Вы пытаетесь (где-то еще) автоматически подключить бин типа `A`. Что-то вроде:

```
@Autowired 
private A beanA;
```

Но у вас есть 2 бина, которые соответствуют этому типу.

Вы можете решить эту проблему, используя JSR-250 аннотацию `@Resource` и указав, какой именно бин:

```
@Resource ("b") 
private A beanA;
```

(где `b` - это имя подставляемго бина) или с помощью аннотации `@Qualifier`.